# How to merge two 2D arrays with conditions of columns values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to merge two 2D NumPy arrays with a specific condition. Let's say we have:

```
A=[[100.121,200.129,1,2,3],
   [105.343,203.347,2,2,1],
   [107.426,201.657,1,3,1],
   [100.121,300.010,1,1,1]]
```

and

```
B=[[107.426,201,675,80],
   [100.121,200.129,70],
   [100.121,300.010,90]]
```

I want to obtain:

```
 C=[[100.121,200.129,1,2,3,70],
   [105.343,203.347,2,2,1,0],
   [107.426,201.657,1,3,1,80],
   [100.121,300.010,1,1,1,90]]
```

So, when the values of the first and the second column match, take the third column in B and append it to A.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code to show 2d structure.

Comment: You forgot to post how you attempted to solve this problem.

Comment: These aren't 2D arrays (and none are valid Python).

Comment: It is not clear if you want a solution on numpy arrays, or on lists. The edge case that there is no matching row in B is also unclear. Should such rows be dropped? Sentinel value? Currently, the code has ints only, so using `np.nan` would not be possible. Is this a true limitation?

Comment: What you want is a equivalent to a SQL left join. If the dataset is very large, consider using some database engine. If the dataset is medium, use pandas. If the dataset is small, use some regular python. It seems to my that numpy is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: I better explain my data. I have two pointclouds (.las file) of the same area; in one point cloud I have x y z and intensity information; in the other pointcloud I have x y z and a class value. I want to merge these two point clouds in one, with points having x,y,z, intensity, and class information. my idea was to look for the same points in the two pointclouds (using x y z coordinates) and append the class to the first pointcloud, the one with the intensity value. so my final pointcloud would have 5 attributes. I'm new in Python, I don't know how to start!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
A=[[100,200,1,2,3],
   [105,203,2,2,1],
   [107,201,1,3,1]]
B=[[107,201,80],
   [100,200,70],
   [105,203,50]]

temp_B = list(zip(*B))
d_B = dict(zip(temp_B[0], temp_B[2]))
A = [i + [d_B.get(i[0],0)] for i in A]
# [[100, 200, 1, 2, 3, 70], [105, 203, 2, 2, 1, 50], [107, 201, 1, 3, 1, 80]]
```

Comment: Ok, and what if the B has less rows than A? in this case, I would like to assign a value equal to 0 to the last (sixth) column. How should I modify your code?

Comment: Can you post that case on question ? I Can help you in that case

Comment: My data are huge, i'll recreate an example:

A=[[100,200,1,2,3],
   [105,203,2,2,1],
   [107,201,1,3,1]]

B=[[107,201,80],
      [100,200,70]]

I am looking for:

 C=[[100,200,1,2,3,70],
       [105,203,2,2,1,0],
       107,201,1,3,1,80]]

Comment: I have changed the code, now it will work with your case as well

Comment: in the third line, do you mean "A = [i + [d_B.get(i[0],0)] for i in A]" ? is "d_B.get" instead of "d.get"?

Comment: Yes @Sbobby it's a typo from my side

Comment: Ok Thanks, it works now.

Making it even more general, what if:
1. values in the first row are equal, and they only differ for the second line? (in my specific case, the first two column are x and y coordinates, and it can happen that the x coordinate of two rows are equal, and they only differ for the y values (and vice-versa).
2. My values are decimal, and when converting the array into a list, it loses some deciman values, and then the algorithm doesn't work well because I cant match the same values in the two matrix.

Hope I was clear! Thanks so far for your help! I'm new to python..

Comment: Do my points get any sense to you?

Comment: Actually it make sense but you need to give me some example to demonstrate these points, that will be better for me to understand your problem more.

Comment: I modified the example in the question. If it is still unclear please let me know!